# SUM of a field within one table, GROUP BY a field in a second table

Tags: sql, vb6, ado

I found how to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` within one table. What I try to do is to sum one field (`Marks.m_GPA`) in one table depending on a field in a second table (`Curriculum.[c_Subject Group]`).

I have one table with all the results of the students named `Marks` and another table named `Curriculum`. Both tables have the subject code in common (`c_Code` and `m_Code`), the `Curriculum` table has got one field `[c_Subject Group]`. I want to have the sum of all `m_GPA` values for each `[c_Subject Group]` and the results `GROUP BY [c_Subject Group]`.

All fields are strings (text).

It's an ADO SQL VB6 application where I use the MS Jet engine of Access. I usually try to run a query using Access to test the query beforehand, ACCESS seems to accept my syntax, but the result is an empty table.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
   Curriculum.[c_Subject Group], 
   Sum([m_GPA]) AS Total_GPA 
FROM Curriculum 
   INNER JOIN Marks ON 
      Curriculum.c_Code = Marks.m_Code 
WHERE Curriculum.[c_Subject Group]= "1"
GROUP BY Curriculum.[c_Subject Group];
```

Even if I try `Sum(cdbl(Marks.[m_GPA]))`, the result is an empty table.

Comment: have you heard of white space?

Comment: may want to edit/format this so people will actually read it and try to help.

Comment: Are you sure c_Subject Group = "1" returns any results?  Run your statement without the WHERE criteria and see what results you receive.

Comment: try to use formatting next time

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
SELECT 
     Curriculum.[c_Subject Group],
     Marks.Total_GPA
 FROM Curriculum
 LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT 
     m_Code,
     Sum([m_GPA]) AS Total_GPA
     FROM Marks
     GROUP BY m_Code
)Marks
 ON Curriculum.c_Code = Marks.m_Code 
 WHERE Curriculum.[c_Subject Group]= '1'
```